# Need help in html.. change background, layout

Tags: css, html

I need little help..I bought a theme for OpenCart from ThemeForest. The theme is almost looking what I want:

http://bit.ly/fOyz4D

I want to change the background to another one, but there is a problem around divs, and I can't do that.

What I need to change in layout to get white background in the red square (on the picture):

http://d.pr/gdZb+

I want background something like this:

http://d.pr/nPM6+

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much,

Thomas

Comment: First remove the background from `wrapper` and then change the background of `body`

Comment: You would like the background to be white? or in grey? (I dind't understand)

Comment: @jack: He wants the background to be the third link.

Comment: I want wrapper's bacgkround in white (without header). |||| #wrapper background white, changed body backgound. Now it is looking like this (on localhost): http://d.pr/yTr2+ http://d.pr/VPVE+

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of the coding on that theme, but the closest thing you can do is to do this.

Locate the stylesheet.css file.

Go to line 442, it should be `#container` and add:

```
background:url(pathtoimage.jpg);
```

or if it's within the theme files it may possibly be.

```
background:url(../imagefolder/pathtoimage.jpg);
```

You'll have to do a quick analysis of where the designated folders are, if not do a direct link to the image itself.

But as I said, I don't like how it's coded, this might not give you the exact results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the **#content** div **background-color** to white or #fff in the CSS file? the default name is stylesheet.css but if your are not using the default theme, the name is problably the name of the theme like **mytheme.css**.